# Why does using innerHTML in javascript echo extra quotation?

Tags: javascript, php

I have PHP page have textbox with button and when click on button text in text box insert to database and textbox change to label and that text show on label but when i change label text with javascript echo extra quotation :

php code:

```
echo "<label id='crlabel".$counterRecord."'></label>";
echo "<input name='cr_number1' id='cr_number".$counterRecord."' type='text'>";
echo "<input class='pad' type='button'  id='cr".$counterRecord."' style='background-color:#428bca' value='s'>";
```

js code:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
(function(cr) {
    $("#cr"+cr).click(function () {
        $.get("cr.php", {
            id: $("#recordid"+cr).val(),
            cr_number:'"' +$("#cr_number"+cr).val()+ '"'
        },function(data){if(data =="cr"){
        alert("cr submitted before you");}else{
$("#cr_number"+cr).fadeOut(500);
        $("#cr"+cr).fadeOut(500);
        document.getElementById('crlabel'+cr).innerHTML = data;
        $("#crlabel"+cr).fadeIn(500);});            
    }
});

})(i);}
```

cr.php:

```
$cr_number=$_GET['cr_number'];
if ($row["cr_number"]!=""){
echo "cr";}
else{mysql_query("UPDATE cr SET cr_number=".$cr_number." WHERE id=".$id.";",$con);echo $cr_number;}
```

this code work fine but i doesn't like extra qoutation start and end of data show
example: "3443"
what I want:3443

Comment: use `\"` to avoid this

Comment: @ddeadlink how?

Comment: This is scary code.  For the love of God, [please sanitise your database queries](http://bobby-tables.com/).  And stop using PHP's **deprecated** `mysql_*` functions in new code; use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You pass the following data

```
{
            id: $("#recordid"+cr).val(),
            cr_number:'"' +$("#cr_number"+cr).val()+ '"'
        }
```

where you add a quote to the start and end of `cr_number`. As a result `$_GET['cr_number']` will hold those quotes inside the values and when you

```
echo $cr_number;
```

the quotes will be in the response. So the response contains the quotes and when you put it into `innerHTML`, it will contain them. To modify this behavior to not contain the quotes, make sure you do not add them in the first place to the data:

```
{
            id: $("#recordid"+cr).val(),
            cr_number:$("#cr_number"+cr).val()
        }
```

Comment: but in database wasn't insert  ".

Comment: if it haven't qoutation my data not insert in database. i should send "

Comment: @aynaz you did not share the code where you insert data to your database. Also, mysql_query is deprecated as all mysql_* functions. Use mysqli_* instead or PDO. Also, you need to make sure your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, I do not see why " would be needed to be able to insert data in your case. If you use ', that's another thing, but then you will need to use it where you generate your query and not to generate it into the GET parameters. You will need to edit your question and add more information. Let me know when it was done.

Comment: @aynaz thank you. Can you give me the definition of your cr table? What is the type of its cr_number field?

Comment: cr type is text

Comment: @aynaz in that case apostrophes around that value should fix the issue, but I strongly suggest that you should refactor your code, as it is uses deprecated functionalities and it is highly unsafe and easy to hack. The suggestion for your current code would be mysql_query("UPDATE cr SET cr_number='".$cr_number."' WHERE id=".$id.";",$con); but that will not fix your SQL injection vulnerability. So I think you should do this for now, but upgrade your code to use PDO afterwards.